Question about Poisson brackets and classical Virasoro generators in bosonic string
I am reading "String Theory and M theory" by Becker, Becker & Schwartz.
I am confused about the following. They state that:

"Classically the vanishing of the energy–momentum tensor translates into the
vanishing of all the Fourier modes
$L_m=0$ for $m=0,±1,±2,...$ Eq 2.77"

Then they state that

"In the classical theory the Virasoro generators satisfy the algebra (poisson brackets):"
$$ [L_m,L_n] = i(m−n)L_{m+n}.\tag{2.84}$$

My question is: why would you calculate the poisson bracket of zero? In the expression they seem not to commute but it actually looks like $[0,0]=0$?
On the other hand, they are supposed to be the generators of some conformal transformations, so they should never be zero.
I am sure I am missing something very basic here.


Note that Poisson brackets should be evaluated before using EOMs (including constraints); not after.

Classically the Virasoro generators are first-class constraint functions that generate reparametrization gauge symmetry. Their solutions vanish, i.e. they vanish on-shell.



So if they vanish, what is the meaning of EQ. 2.84 (in the classical theory)?

May be my question should be, what does it mean that the generators of a symmetry are all zero, they would generate the trivial group. Is it the same as when you have a scalar and the representations of the rotation group becomes trivial?

I updated the answer.
